# Как получить значение из php в js

Tags: javascript, render

Как получить первые два и последние два выводимых из output тэга  и поместить в js отдельно от остального? Как это можно сделать хотя бы для одного набора тэгов из массива?  Вот такие данные я получаю в js:

```
[output] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => "
<a class="item"><</a>
<a class="item"><<</a>
<a id="1" class="item">1</a>
<a class="item" data-pag="catsfilter.php?page=2">2</a>
<a class="item">></a>
<a class="item">>></a>
 
                ")
 
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => "
<a class="item"><</a>
<a class="item"><<</a>
<a id="1" class="item">1</a>
<a class="item" data-pag="catsfilter.php?page=2">2</a>
<a class="item">></a>
<a class="item">>></a>
")
 
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => "
<a class="item"><</a>
<a class="item"><<</a>
<a id="1" class="item">1</a>
<a class="item" data-pag="catsfilter.php?page=2">2</a>
<a class="item">></a>
<a class="item">>></a>
")
```

Передать я пытаюсь сюда, чтобы получилось что-то вроде `${page.arrowsStart}` `${page.arrowsEnd}`:

```
const { output } = JSON.parse(response);

        var pag = $('.pag').empty();
        output[i].forEach(page =>
        {
            const card = getItemHTML(page);
            pag.append(card);
        });

function getItemPAG(page)
{
    const pagHTML = `
        <div class="1">${page.arrowsStart}</div>
        <div class="2">${page.base}</div>
        <div class="3">${page.arrowsEnd</div>`;

    return pagHTML;
}
```

Comment: Можете разбить результат на массив используя регулярное выражение `const links = page.match(/<a [^>]*>[^<]*<\/a>/g);` и потом элементы с нужными ключами подставить куда Вам нужно.